# New tag (real) of questionable utility

Tags: discussion, tagging

A new tag, [(real)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real), was created today and applied to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113378/comparing-real-and-complex-numbers) about the real numbers as a subset of the complex numbers. I feel that this question fits perfectly well under the tag (complex-numbers) alone, and furthermore I cannot think of a question which would fit under the tag (real) better than it would under (real-analysis) or (complex-numbers), (quaternions), etc. if it's about the reals as a subset of some larger structure. Should the tag be deleted, and if so would a user with appropriate privileges be kind enough to oblige?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. In the future, you don't need to ask a meta question to do this; just flag or make a suggested edit.

Comment: Thanks, will do.